# How to solve the Python error "NameError: name 'X' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
      id_check(id,gender)
NameError: name 'gender' is not defined
```

And this is my simple code :

```
#!/bin/python3 
def clear_line():
    print("\n")

def id_check(id,gender):
                    
    id = input(" Do you have an id? : ")    


    if (id == "yes" ) or (id == "Yes") or (id == "y"):
        
        id = True   
    
    elif (id == "no" ) or (id == "No") or (id == "n"):
        
        print ("I need your id")
                
    else:
        print ("Please respound with yes or no "), 
        clear_line()
        id_check(id)

    gender = input(" What is you gender ? ")
    print (gender)

id_check(id,gender)
```

Comment: gender is not defined outside id_check

Comment: Those variables, id and gender, are things you will read in inside the function. They should not be function parameters.

Comment: don't use recursion, use a loop. If I anwers 20 times "42" before providing a valid answer I am 20 times deep into stacked calls of your function with build up stackframes which is not needed. coming back from those calls I get asked 20 times after my gender ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your function, your asking the user to add a variable that will be the gender. However, the variable you give, gender, is not defined. Therefore, it raises an error.

To fix it, remove the parameters from the function, like this:

```python
def clear_line():
    print("\n")

def id_check():
                    
    id = input(" Do you have an id? : ")    


    if (id == "yes" ) or (id == "Yes") or (id == "y"):
        
        id = True   
    
    elif (id == "no" ) or (id == "No") or (id == "n"):
        
        print ("I need your id")
                
    else:
        print ("Please respound with yes or no "), 
        clear_line()
        id_check(id)

    gender = input(" What is you gender ? ")
    print (gender)

id_check()
```

Comment: one other thing: you should not shadow built-in functions like "id". Better use "id_" or something else

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped!

Comment: And another one: do not recurse if you do not need to ... use a loop / break. Try answering wrongly 5 times, then correct to see why...